# C# if directive

Tags: c#, visual-studio, directive

Can I write in code to set the variable to true or false depending on a button I pressed? See example below.

If not, what other ways are there to achieve similar effects? I have already marked the codes for different modes using directives and only want developers to have the option of switching the modes, but now I wish to give the user the option of switching between the modes. The choice of the mode will only be given at the start of the program, and user is not allowed to switch the mode. To switch the mode, he can only restart the program again.

If cannot use directives, what is the fastest way can I use? (note: the statements are all around the solution)

In pseduocode of what I wish to achieve:

```
void button_click(...){
    if(!CONDITION)
        CONDITION = true;
    else
        CONDITION = false;
}


...
#if CONDITION
   //mode X with addtional steps
#endif
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. You want to toggle a member boolean with a button?

Comment: Maybe the qn wasn't clear... i meant cos the if directives statements are throughout the entire solution which consists of many projects. So i want to find out if there is a shortcut for this to be implemented as a functionality for user by clicking on a button to togger the execution of these statements (not just one but many). Previously the choice to execute these statements or not are just the developer, now i would like the user to have the flexibility to do so as well

Answer (score 5):

You are using a preprocessor directive and trying to set it from code which defeats the purpose, even if it were to be possible (I'm pretty sure you can't). Why not use a regular boolean field as a flag ?

```
private bool Condition {get; set;}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible. The if statement is executed at run time, but preprocessor directives like `#IF` are executed at compile time. You need to decide at compile time how to build the code, and somewhere in your project (say in the project's properties) or at the top of the source file, set `CONDITION` to whatever you need it to be for that given build.

If this really needs to be a runtime decision, then you need to include all the possible code paths and decide at runtime which one to take.

Comment: So what can i do now if i can't use directives? To add to every part of the code with these statements a bool check using a global variable?

Answer (score 0):

If your asking if you can conditional compile something based upon a condition in your code the answer is no.  The complier must know at compile time what to include in your assembly.  You can almost certainly achieve what you are attempting with out conditional compilation however what are you attempting to do?

Comment: i hv made more explanation in the qn

Answer (score 0):

The '#IF' directive is used for conditional compilation, which means it looks for tokens defined at compile time and literally compiles or does not compile particular code.  This means the non-compiled code is not part of your program and cannot be used at runtime.  You will need to modify your code to use normal flags rather than conditional compilation if you want to change behavior at runtime.  That said, you may want to consider a deeper design review, as adding new branching functionality based on configuration flags can lead to messy code very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

These directives provide the ability to conditionally skip sections of source files, to report error and warning conditions, and to delineate distinct regions of source code
You cannot change them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The `#IF` directive is a preprocessor option and will have no meaning once you compile the code so you can't use these to control program flow after compilation.

As for your other options, you should be able to convert them to class-level variables rather easily but, on the negative side, your code will be littered with `if CONDITION ... else ...` statements that *could* end up being a pain in the butt to manage.

Another more OOP-friendly option, is to implement the [State](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) pattern.  You could encapsulate the behavior of each "Condition" into its own State and toggle between them in the pattern.  This could be overkill for two states (most likely is).

Another reference:  http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternState.aspx

Comment: I don't mean 2 diff states, rather 2 diff modes. One mode just have more statements to be executed then the other mode. I think I will only implement the choice of the mode at the beginning of the program, not during the program, cos of initializating statements...I hv added more info to the qn, pls check it out.

Comment: @yeeen:  Reread the links about the State pattern.  It will still cover what you want in a nice, clean way.

Answer (score 0):

`#IF` is determined at compile time, and you want to change it at runtime. It is impossible.